# How do I find the file something was defined in using gdb?

Tags: debugging, path, gdb

When I type `list mystruct` into gdb, I receive the lines of code used to define  mystruct. How can I ask gdb to give me the file it is reading from to print those lines? Getting that file from the gdb python interface would be preferable. The more easily parsable the better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For showing definition of a type there is a command **ptype**:

```
$ ptype mystruct
...
```

To know where type is defined, command **info types *regex***:

```
$ info types ^mystruct$
<filename>:<line>
```

And to print lines of source file, command **list *filename:start_line,filename:end_line***:

```
$ list myfile.c:100,myfile.c:110
```

if not enough

```
$ list +
```

Note that there is possible several same type definitions, so **info types** can give several locations.

**Update**

Since this is a matter of compatibility between compiler (that generates debugging information, e.g. DWARF) and **gdb** that reads it, for some reason, it's not always possible to retrieve detailed information, e.g. line number. This can be workaround-ed by using specific tools, e.g. for DWARF there is a **[dwarfdump](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dwarfdump.1.html)** tool, that has access to all DWARF information in the file. The output for structure type

```
struct mystruct {
  int i;
  struct sample *less;
}
```

looks like:

```
$ dwarfdump -ie ./a.out
... 
< 1><0x00000079>    structure_type
       name                        "mystruct"
       byte_size                   0x0000000c
       decl_file                   0x00000002 ../sample.h
       decl_line                   0x00000003
       sibling                     <0x000000a8>
< 2><0x00000085>      member
       name                        "i"
       decl_file                   0x00000002 ../sample.h
       decl_line                   0x00000004
       type                        <0x0000004f>
       data_member_location        0
< 2><0x0000008f>      member
       name                        "less"
       decl_file                   0x00000002 ../sample.h
       decl_line                   0x00000005
       type                        <0x000000a8>
       data_member_location        4
```

Here you have information on which line not only type declaration starts, but also line number for each member.

The output format is not very convenient, and heavy - you should write your own parser. But it could be better to write your own tool using [libdwarf](http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=Libdwarf_And_Dwarfdump) or utilize [pyelftools](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools) on python. [Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E410/update/p0/symtabgen.py) is one of examples.

Comment: The second command looks like what I'm looking for; however, when I try it on my end, it just gives: 
"All types matching regular expression ""^mystruct$"":"
The regex doesn't seem to match.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized removed the quotes around "^mystruct$" worked. Your response lists both filename and line number, but gdb only gave me file name. Is there something extra to do to get it to print out the line number?

Comment: @Matt check my update, I played with gcc/gdb and couldn't get line numbers visible, even though they are stored in dwarf in file, need to dig into gdb sources why is that... But since you mentioned python, pyelftools is the way to go for you...

Comment: My only concern about using a tool like dwarfdump pyelftools is that dwarf isn't the debug symbol format. Do these tools work if the executable is compiled with STABS or another format?

Comment: @Matt STAB and DWARF are both debbugging data formats. STAB is quite old and have limited support, so DWARF is more widely used. In which format your compiler generates debugging data? (you can check do  your binaries have .stab section or .debug_xxx sections with **readelf**)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have compiled with debug information (-g3) option,
you can use:
`info macro mystruct`
e.g
 `info macro SOCK_RAW`

(gdb) info macro SOCK_RAW

**`Defined at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket_type.h:33`**
included at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:38
included at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:38
included at /home/nirl/cpp_tut/filter/filter.cpp:1

``