# How can I find parent header file of a structure/function in C?

Tags: c++, c, grep, ubuntu-14.04

I'll be as brief as possible.
I've a **main.c** file that includes several header files "**header1.h**", "**header2.h**", ... and so on. In "**main.c**", a variable is declared using a user defined structure. But I don't know the location of that structure (It must be present in one of those header files or some other header file included in one of those header files in "**main.c**"). My question is, if I can use "***grep***" in anyway to find the parent file of that structure? If not "***grep***", what else can be done? And I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `grep -rnw --color . -e "structure_name"`

Comment: You can use an `IDE`, like `Eclipse`, that gives you `find in files` search.

Comment: Are you really asking how to perform a text search for a class or function name in your codebase? Did this really get 4 upvotes already? Barmy.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet incredible...... ;)

Comment: I disagree. This is an intriguing question, and well posed. A good answer will mention that many compilers support an option to run just the preprocessor. A perception of being obvious should not be a motivation for downvoting. The fact that black holes radiate energy is obvious to some folk.

Comment: This is the sort of thing an `IDE` will do for you. I use `eclipse` and `F3` takes me to the *definition/declaration* of a symbol.

Comment: If you can compile the program, see the answers to [How do I find the file something was defined in using gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928451/how-do-i-find-the-file-something-was-defined-in-using-gdb)

Comment: @Bathsheba: I'm pretty sure "finding text in files on your computer" is above our desired level of obviousness on an enthusiast/professional programming Q&A. I wonder why the OP doesn't simply _read the code_.

Answer (score 4):

Because the preprocessor just copies all `#include`d files into place, you can run that, and look in the preprocessed output - it leaves notation in place showing the file boundaries:

`SO1.h`:

```
#ifndef SO1_H
#define SO1_H
struct Foo {};
#endif
```

`SO2.h`:

```
#ifndef SO2_H
#define SO2_H
#include "SO1.h"
#endif
```

`SO.cpp`:

```
#include "SO2.h"
int main(){}
```

Now since you are on Ubuntu, I assume you are using gcc (or clang, but it accepts the same option). If you pass the `-E` flag, it only runs the preprocessor, then dumps the output:

```
# 1 "SO.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "SO.cpp"
# 1 "SO2.h" 1


# 1 "SO1.h" 1


struct Foo {};
# 4 "SO2.h" 2
# 2 "SO.cpp" 2
int main(){}
```

We can see that the file label immediately above the `struct Foo` is `SO1.h`, which is where that `struct` is defined.

This works equally well for C and C++ (though I have used C++ in my example). However, normally you should pick only a single language for a question.

---

If you know that the `struct` you search for is somewhere in your current project (i.e. somewhere in your current directory), you can indeed use basic command line tools such as `grep`. For instance

```
grep -Hn "\<struct Foo\>" *.{h,c,cpp}
```

will tell you the file and line of matching source code files. I regularly use a little script I put at `~/bin/srcgrep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
RE="$1"
shift 1
find $@ \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.c" \) -exec grep263 -EHn --colour=always "$RE" {} \;
```

Then

```
srcgrep "\<struct Foo\>" dir1 dir2
```

will search all source code files anywhere (including subdirectories) under `dir1` and `dir2`.

A more advanced tool is [`ack!`](http://beyondgrep.com/).